# Bad encoding from database in php file using IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis, encoding

I must migrate large database and large php systems from php4 to php5.

Databases tables stored in UTF-8 format, but the data contain windows-1257;

All page in header is:

But I get data from database like this: AutomobiliĆø stovĆ«jimo;

var_dump(mysql_client_encoding($connect)); return utf8;

File encoding: windows-1257;

In Apache server (try Wamp in W7 and Windows server 2012) get normal data.
But IIS dont.. Mb IIS dont understand file encoding or etc..

I give up, and I need your help...

---

SOVLED: I change  mysql configuration (my.ini) and set character_set_server utf8 to latin1
And now var_dump(mysql_client_encoding($connect)); return latin1;
And all projects works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Databases tables stored in UTF-8 format, but the data contain
>   windows-1257.

Try converting the data from Windows-1257 to UTF-8 with something like:

```
$encoded = iconv ( "CP1257", "UTF-8", $string );
```

Comment: In wamp all its ok but in windows server I get this error: PHP Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\archyvas\test.php

Comment: My data in table is "Gatviø Ðilalëje nëra" must be Gatvių Šilalėje nėra